# How to open windows explorer at 'This PC'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, operating-system

How can I open Windows Explorer at 'This PC', using python 3.6 when using Windows 10?
I am not sure what the path is to 'This PC'. (Previously 'My Computer'). I am able to open Windows Explorer to known paths using:

```
import os

os.startfile(os.path.realpath(DIRECTORY_PATH))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I played around, and there is no simple path I can find that leads to "This PC".

I found [this](https://ss64.com/nt/explorer.html) page though that goes over the arguments you can give to `explorer.exe`, and saw `,`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["explorer", ","])
```

Comment: `os.system("explorer.exe  file:")`

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/228896/in-windows-run-command-line-how-to-open-my-computer

Comment: (I ended up rewriting the whole answer since I found a better way after posting)